# Run another MVC project on same solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two MVC projects in one solution,

-Project1.Client (startup)

-Project2.Admin

On the Project2.Admin, I created a new controller ("Clients") but accessing returns 404 error page like (http://localhost:port/admin/clients).

How to invoke the other Admin project while the Project1.Client is the startup?

I don't know if I have to go with Areas for the Project2.Admin because I wanted to use the same configuration found at Project1.Client web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the admin project.  Right click the admin project, go to Debug, click Start New Instance (assuming you're in Visual Studio).

Comment: Will there be any issues if both projects sits on the same domain?

Comment: Yes, you bind a domain to an application. You could get around this by using sub-domains eg `yourapp.com` & `admin.yourapp.com` or virtual directories

Comment: Both projects should have different ports which will point IIS / IIS Express to the correct location.

Comment: great thanks let you know how it goes once I do the publish.